# Maximum number of Facebook private message sent by Graph API (per day)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph API to send private message as shown in this documentation

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/

Now, I want to ask about the Maximum number of Facebook private message sent by Graph API (per day)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully, applications can not send private messages via the API (or any other methods).

What you are looking at is the documentation for **reading the inbox**.

Comment: They can send messages using the chat API.

Comment: The chat API is not the same as private messages.

Comment: I'm open to being corrected on this, but I believe nowadays they are in fact the same thing. If you use an external chat client to message someone (presumably using the chat API), it will appear in their private messages.

They certainly used to be separate systems but not anymore I believe.

Comment: @RafiqManiar: I know this is off topic, but I would love to know how messages are sent. Any pointers on that?

Comment: I'm sure you all can appreciate the problem that would arise if applications were allowed to send chat or private messages to users. Imagine the possibilities of spamming users!  I'm not saying @justme wants to spam anyone... I'm just saying that Facebook doesn't provide this functionality for a reason.

Comment: @Lix: I do. But not everyone has ulterior motives for implementing such a feature. Personally, I would love to use it in my Android app to make it a more complete app where users will also be able to reply to Inbox messages rather than just looking at them and then going elsewhere to reply to them.

Comment: You are talking about chat messages and not private messages. There is a difference.  You **can** send chat messages. [Read here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/)

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook Chat API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) is the same as private messages.

An easily way to test is, install [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im) and log in Facebook Chat with pidgin.
Try to send some messages to other friends and browse "Messages" section in Facebook website.
You will find that all messages sent through Pidgin will appear in Facebook Messages.
And also we could use me/inbox or me/outbox connection of Graph API to retrieve those messages sent through Pidgin.

It is the only way to send messages to friends as I know.
Without special API key in whitelist, it could not send private message by Graph API.